# Proving $4 \nmid n^2+2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, divisibility

I was asked to prove $4 \nmid n^2+2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and I was wondering whether my procedure was correct.

$I$. Assume $n$ is even, or rather $n = 2Q, Q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Assume as well $4|n^2+2$. Then

$$n^2+2=4q \tag{$q\in\mathbb{Z}$}$$

$$\implies (2Q)^2+2 =4q$$
$$\implies 2=4(q-Q^2)$$

Our result implies $4|2$, which is absurd. Then if $n$ is even it can not happen $4|n^2+2$.

$II.$ Assume $n=2Q+1, Q\in\mathbb{Z}$. Assume $4|n^2+2$. Then

$$n^2+2=4$$
$$\implies (2Q+1)^2+2=4q$$
$$\implies 4Q^2+4Q+3=4q$$
$$\implies 3=4(q-Q^2-Q)$$

which implies $4|3$, which is absurd. Then if $n$ is odd, $4\nmid n^2+2$.

$III.$ We've shown $4|n^2+2$ is absurd if $n$ is odd and if $n$ is even. Thus we have shown $4\nmid n^2+2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I have the two general questions one has when finishing a proof. $A)$ Is the proof correct? $B)$ Was there a simpler proof? In this case, perhaps a proof that could be directly applied to all integers instead of having to show the property for even and odd numbers separately?

Comment: You can take the set of quadratic residues modulo $4$ (which are $0,1$), add $2$ to each, then note that the resulting set has no members which are $0\mod 4$.

Comment: The standard way is to frame this mod 4. By taking mod $4$, you only need to consider $n = 0, 1, 2, 3$, whose squares are $0, 1, 0, 1$ respectively.

Comment: Suppose $n^2+2=4k$ then $n^2=2(2k-1)$, so $n^2$ is even=> $n$ is even=>$n=2q$=>$4q^2=2(2k-1)$=>$2q^2=2k-1$, which is no satisfied because RHS is odd, LHS is even.

Comment: For the odd case it's a little less calculation intensive to say that if $n$ odd then $n^2$ is odd, so that $n^2+2$ must also be odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Here is another perhaps simpler one. Suppose you can have $4\mid (n^2+2)$ for some $n$. Then you can express $n^2+2 = 4m$ for some $m$. So $n^2 = 2(2m-1)$. This shows $2 \mid n^2 \implies 2 \mid n$ and this allows you to write $n = 2p$ for some $p$. Hence $n^2 = (2p)^2 = 4p^2=4m-2\implies 2p^2=2m-1$. This can't happen since the LSH is even and the RHS is odd. Therefore $4 \nmid (n^2+2)$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome @lafinur. Any time buddy.

Answer (score 3):

Same ideas but shorter: If $n$ is even then $n=2Q$, $Q\in\mathbb{Z}$, thus
$$
(n^2+2)÷4=(4Q^2+2)÷4=Q^2+\frac12\not\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
If $n$ is odd then $n^2+2$ is odd, so $4\not\mid n^2+2$.

Comment: This answer was very good, such a simpler approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think of to prove this is to consider even and odd numbers separatedly.

$(2k)^2+2=4k^2+2$ which is not divisible by $4$

$(2k+1)^2+2=4k^2+4k+1+2=4(k^2+k)+3$ which is not divisible by $4$

Answer (score 2):

Do you know Euler's theorem? We have $n^2\equiv 1\pmod4$, when $n$ and $4$ are relatively prime.

That takes care of $1$ and $3$.

$0$ is clear.

All that's left is $n=2$.  But $2^2\equiv 0\not\equiv-2\pmod 4$.

Comment: No, I do not know the theorem (I self study so my knowledge is a bit disperse). I appreciate you pointing out that it may be of use, I will study it during the week and try to apply it.